# Replicate loft-based object to value-driven object

Tags: mechanical-engineering, solidworks, cad, technical-drawing, drafting

I've made the following oddity in Solidworks:

[image: 3D object in 3D viewer, front]

[image: 3D object in 3D viewer, isometric]

[image: 3D object in 2D drawing, front, with dimensions]

[image: 3D object in 2D drawing, top, with dimensions]

All the dimensions are known except for the top part. This is probably because this was done using the Lofted Boss/Base feature. The Loft profile goes (top-view) from the big circle at 90° to the small circle at 180°.

Now I know what the part should look like, I want to copy the exact dimensions so I can replicate this effect with proper tools that do work with adjustable values and dimensions.

How would I got about that? It's basically a feature between two circles, so a combination of a Spline and Sweep seems like a good start. Getting the values right would probably take some work but is doable (the thin part of the neck is roughly 10mm). But then? Do I need a helix of sorts to get that twist in? I have no idea on how to continue from here.

Comment: Your loft is not fully defined, as evidenced by the twist artefacts. This part should be made with a revolve, not a loft.